# Flu-i-dez ou flui-dez?

Tags: divisão-silábica

Estava verificando a separação silábica da palavra fuidez.

[Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fluidez):
Flu·i·dez |u-i...ê|

[Michalis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=fluidez):
Flui.dez

[Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/fluidez):
Flu:i. dez.
O que significa os dois pontos em "flu:i"?

Qual é a separação silábica correta de fuidez?

Comment: Eu digo *flu.i.dez*, três sílabas. Acho que em Portugal toda a gente pronuncia assim.

Comment: Pelo que vi pesquisando sobre o novo Acordo Ortográfico, enquanto fluido, o ditongo ui é inseparável, seus derivados podem ter o ui separável. Por isso você tem razão fluidez, tem três sílabas, enquanto fluido, apenas 02. Embora haja pessoas pronunciando de forma errada flu-í-do...

Comment: @tdmsoares Talvez confusão com o particípio passado de *fluir*, que é de facto *flu.í.do*.

Comment: @Jacinto Bem Lembrado! Mas às vezes a pronúncia incorreta do substantivo fluido acaba se arrastando para outras palavras, por exemplo: gra-tu-í-to

Comment: No Brasil tem muita gente que diz *flu.í.do* – o que me dói no ouvido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com o novo Acordo ortográfico, fluido, separa-se flui-do, o ditongo ui é inseparável.

Entretanto, nas palavras derivadas como fluidez, é separável. Portanto flu-i-dez.

Deve ser esse motivo da palavra estar nos dicionários com os dois pontos ":"

Referência: [Os ditongos e o Novo Acordo Ortográfico](http://www.planetaeducacao.com.br/portal/artigo.asp?artigo=1357)

Answer (score 4):

Os dois pontos na entrada do Aulete significam que a a sequência pode ser pronunciada tanto como ditongo [uj] como hiato [ui]. Portanto, o Aulete admite ambas as hipóteses.

A juntar ao Priberam, também o dicionário da Academia/Verbo e o Houaiss indicam que há hiato (contrariamente a *fluido*). Também foi assim que sempre ouvi.

A indicação do Michalis (e a do Aulete)  parece indicar a existência de alguma variabilidade. Acho estranho, geralmente o fenómeno que existe é no sentido contrário (por exemplo, *gratuito*, pronunciado normalmente com ditongo, é por algumas pessoas pronunciado com hiato), mas há gente para tudo.

Comment: Resta ainda saber por que é que Aulete indica *flu:i.dez* e não *flu.i.dez*.

Comment: Encontrei aqui a resposta: https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ajuda:Nota_sobre_a_divis%C3%A3o_sil%C3%A1bica_e_o_acento_t%C3%B4nico_das_proparox%C3%ADtonas_aparentes

Comment: Se bem que ao contrário do que essa página diz, "sério" tem só duas silabas no português padrão de Portugal (de Lisboa).

Comment: Perguntei na ABL, e eles só me informaram a divisão silábica da palavra fluidez, mas não se é ditongo ou hiato...

Comment: @tdmsoares Qual divisão eles indicaram?

Comment: @bfavaretto Eles indicaram assim: flu.i.dez