# Questão de concurso: existe apenas uma resposta correta?

Tags: separação-silábica

Participei de um concurso e caiu a seguinte questão:

> [QUESTÃO 05](http://promunicipio.com/arquivos/20151220_235413_TAE_TECNOLOGO_AN_DESENV_DE_SISTEMAS_RC_GTI.pdf) - Marque a opção em que TODAS as palavras estão separadas CORRETAMENTE:
>
> A) Flu-i-dez, no-da, ca-pa-ci-da-de, a-li-men-to;
> B) Frui-ção, tra-pa-ça, au-ment-o, sal-se-i-ro;
> C) Flui-dez, fru-i-ção, sal-sei-ro, ca-paz;
> D)Sal-sei-ro, fun-cio-nar, flu-i-dez, tra-pa-ça.

Marquei a letra "A", mas o gabarito preliminar diz que é a "C". Várias pessoas entraram com recursos, no entanto, a banca manteve a letra "C".

Analisamos a separação silábica de **fluidez**, [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/flu-i-dez-ou-flui-dez). Chegamos à conclusão que a separação melhor é **flu-i-dez**, neste caso, considerando que as outras palavras da opção "A" também estão com separação silábica corretas, a letra "A" pode ser a resposta a mais adequada. Entretanto, parece existir mais de uma opção correta, como a letra D, ou mesmo a letra C se considerarmos que **fluidez** pode também ser separada com ditongo ao invés de hiato **flui-dez**.

Existe apenas uma resposta correta nessa questão? Quais? Porquê?

Comment: Não entendo como esta pergunta é diferente da outra. Acho que a pergunta original, "qual é correta?", já inclui "existe uma ou mais do que uma que é correta?".

Comment: @DanGetz Creio que o Denis se refere à pergunta dentro da pergunta: se só uma das respostas entre as A, B, C, D está correta, ou se mais do que uma está. A questão aqui está também no *funcionar*. *fun.cio.nar* ou *fun.ci.o.nar*?

Comment: Acho que entendo agora...então está a perguntar se há outra explicação, para além de uma possível preferência para *flui-dez* da parte do escritor da pergunta?

Comment: Preferência por *flui.dez* e *fru.i.ção* explicam a preferência do autor da pergunta. Mas os dicionário no seu conjunto admitem divisões alternativas para *fluides, fruição* e *funcionar* que justificam as respostas A e D também.

Comment: @DanGetz, é como o Jacinto comentou. Refiro-me à pergunta dentro da pergunta. A minha dúvida inicialmente, quando fiz a pergunta sobre "flui-dez ou flu-i-dez", era somente sobre essa palavra, agora envolve outras também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As palavras que estão aqui em dúvida são apenas ***fluidez, fruição*** e ***funcionar***. *Salseiro* é evidentemente *sal.sei.ro*. O problema agora é que os dicionários dão respostas diferentes.

De acordo com o Priberam e o Portal da Língua Portuguesa (baseado em Portugal) a alínea correta é a ***A*** porque a divisão silábica correta é:

> [*flu.i.dez*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=64094), [*fru.i.ção*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=125442) e [*fun.ci.o.nar*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=87326)

Mas de acordo com o Michaelis a resposta correta é a ***C*** porque a divisão siábica é:

> [*Flui.dez*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=fluidez), [*fru.i.ção*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=frui%E7%E3o) e [*fun.cio.nar*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=funcionar)

Finalmente de acordo com o Aulete as respostas ***A, C*** e ***D*** estão corretas. O Aulete admite várias possibilidades para a divisão silábica destas três palavras, razoavelmente, dada as divergências dos dicionários anteriores. Os dois pontos marcam uma divisão opcional:

> [*flu:i.dez*](http://www.aulete.com.br/fluidez), [*fru:i.ção*](http://www.aulete.com.br/frui%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e [*fun.ci:o.nar*](http://www.aulete.com.br/funcionar)

Ou seja, o Aulete admite

> *flui.dez* e *flu.i.dez*; *frui.ção* e *fru.i.ção*; *fun.cio.nar* e *fun.ci.o.nar*

Answer (score 3):

Qualquer dúvida que haja sobre a legitimidade da separação silábica de *fluidez* em *flu-i-dez* tem de ultrapassar o facto de que esta separação é precisamente dada como exemplo no acordo ortográfico de 1990 (base XX, 4.):

> As vogais consecutivas que não pertencem a ditongos decrescentes (as que pertencem a ditongos deste tipo nunca se separam: ai-roso, cadei-ra, insti-tui, ora-ção, sacris-tães, traves-sões) podem, se a primeira delas não é u precedido de g ou q, e mesmo que sejam iguais, separar-se na escrita: ala-úde, áre-as, ca-apeba, co-ordenar, do-er, **flu-idez**, perdo- as, vo-os. O mesmo se aplica aos casos de contiguidade de ditongos, iguais ou diferentes, ou de ditongos e vogais: cai-ais, caí-eis, ensai-os, flu-iu.

A resposta correta é portanto **A**.

Isto aplica-se para efeitos de translineação, entenda-se; a pronúnicia das palavras não é regida por nenhum documento legal. Em Lisboa, *funcionar* tem 3 sílabas, noutras zonas do país tem 4, por exemplo. Ainda assim, segundo o texto citado, uma separação em *funci-onar* é legítima independentemente de quem a escreva porque se trata de um ditongo crescente.

Comment: O Michaelis indica *fun.cio.nar*. Isto não indica que eles consideram o *io* como ditongo decrescente?